# How do I determine whether two instances of a Student class represent the same student?

Tags: java

I have a Java class

```
class Student
{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

Also, I have two instances of the Student class `student1` and `student2`.

One way to find out whether both the instances represent the "same student" is to compare the data manually, i.e., the name and age. If they are the same, then they represent the "same student".

Is there any other way to find out whether the two instances represent the "same student"?

P.S. I was asked this question in an interview. I still do not fully understand the phrase "same student". I am guessing it means same student in the real world. If not, what else could the interviewer have meant?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the question. The "same student" could mean the same Java Student object (referential equality operator "==") or the same student data, for which you would need to implement an equals operator. Both answers are given below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What identifies the student?

We don't have anything but a name and an age. Now, you COULD have two people of the same name, but probably not. In any event, I wouldn't consider age to be something that identifies someone - not like a name does.

So I would do this

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!o instanceof Student) return false;
    Student s = (Student)o;
    return o.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

In case you're new to Java, the Object class has a method `public boolean equals(Object o)`. Because EVERY object in Java inherits from Object, they ALL have that method, whether they want it or not. The default implementation simply compares the address in memory. So if you were to do

```
Student s = new Student();
Student t = new Student();
boolean e = (s == t); // always false
boolean q = s.equals(t); // always false if not overridden
```

Now, this particular method that I wrote doesn't do null checks, which you would want to do if it were in production code.

Comment: If the name is unique, then you can for sure use the name. **Whatever makes the Student unique is what should be compared in the `equals` method**.

Comment: Hmm. .basically you are saying, I must have a unique identifier and simply compare it.

Comment: Well not necessarily. For example, what if instead of name, you had `String firstName; String lastName;`? In that case, you wouldn't compare based just on firstName, or compare just on lastName, but you'd compare based on both of them being equal. So John Doe doesn't equal Jane Doe, nor would John Doe equal John Smith.

Comment: Yes, but if I had an ID or something which by design is made unique, then that solves the problem. Right?

Comment: Yes, that'd be great! Perhaps if you had `long studentId` then you could just have `return this.studentId == s.studentId;`

Comment: If this ever comes up in an interview again, I'd also override hashCode too :) http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28 In fact, I would recommend buying and reading the book "Effective Java". It's filled with things every Java developer should know.

Comment: hmm.. adding a Unique ID solves the problem. But I doubt that's the answer they expected. Were they trying to judge me on some other aspect of java, whose application might be the solution to this problem? Is there any other way of finding whether they represent the same real-world object other than comparing unique identifiers?

Comment: It is my understanding that == refers to reference equality, i.e. s == t iff s and t are the same reference, therefore your comment is wrong and == will not return true even if their .equals method was overridden.

Comment: @Senthil My suspicion is that they were judging how familiar you are with standard Java practices. They were probably waiting for you to ask "How should I handle two students with the same name?" or something along those lines.

Comment: @kgrad you are correct that the == operator can be thought of as comparing reference equality. However you have misinterpreted my comment. Allow me to phrase it with more clarity: If you do not override the `equals()` method, and it instead inherits from `Object`, then invoking `equals()` is essentially the same as invoking `==`. Because you do not want to compare based on `==`, you should override `equals()` to ensure comparison by value, not by reference."

Comment: @glowcoder - your comment is very misleading, you say "would be false if we don't override equals()", implying that it would be true if we did...

Comment: @kgrad You're again misinterpreting me. I am not implying that `==` ever changes behavior. Override as many methods as you want, `==` will **never** change. What will change is the behavior of `equals()`. If you do not override `equals()`, the behavior of `equals()` is equivalent to that of `==`. If you do override `equals(), assuming a proper implementation, the behavior of `equals()` should be different than that of `==`. I don't know if I can make it more clear than that!

Comment: @glowcoder better explain this in the answer. I agree with kgrad it is misleading now.

Comment: @Bozho wow... I can't believe I actually wrote that... now everything kgrad said (including his confusion) makes sense.

Comment: @kgrad, Bozho - that's what I meant to say there! :)

Comment: -1: The number of, and good quality of the comments indicates that this answer really needs to be re-written.

Comment: @EliRosencruft I'm not sure what you're getting at here. The first section of comments was explaining the equals contract to OP. The second part was addressing a misleading claim in my answer, but was fixed as soon as the problem was clarified. The answer in its present state is accurate and helpful. Compare revision 1 with revision 2 for background on what's going on. If you have further concerns with the answer, I'm open to hearing those so they may also be addressed.

Comment: @corsiKa Ok, I re-read it. HOw to reverse the downvote? Seems locked.

Comment: @Eli I made a minor edit which will allow you to remove your downvote.

Answer (score 5):

There are two definitions of the same student in Java (if student is an object). There is the case where the student has the same name and age which can be checked by implementing the .equals() method. This means that their values are equal.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //check if the student's age and name are equal
}
```

The second case refers to when two different variables point to the same actual object, this is known as referential equality and can be tested with ==.

```
if (student1 == student2)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning "referential equality". I think that this is the correct answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Really good question, Trying my best and hope it will make you understand...

First copying your text
Your text = "One way to find out whether both the instances represent the "same student" is to compare the data manually, i.e., the name and age. If they are the same, then they represent the "same student." and "I am guessing it means same student in the real world."

Your first stmt is wrong whereas your guess is right. 
In a school there are two students of name Frank and both Frank have same age. Does that means that they are same. No off course not. Even if you compare say 5 datas and it could be possible that those 5 data of two different student matches. In real world it is very easy to look at them and say that they are different.

In the language of java "==" double equals refers to "same" and is called the same instance.

If two reference variable student1 and student2 referes to the same instance this means that they are referring to the same student or in the language of java "same instance of student"

In the context of student == is important and suggest you to read .equals() method to understad more about equality.

Comment: I am confused about instances and references. Please tell me whether i got it right - An instance can have many references to it. But one reference cannot be made to two instances. Am I right?

Comment: The interviewer made it absolutely clear that there were "**two instances**" in his problem. So comparing the two references using `==` or otherwise, is moot. It won't work because the two references CANNOT be the same. Right?

Comment: @Senthil Yes you are right, but if you are confused let me explain with the same example.  Student student1 = new Student("Frank"); Now student1 is a reference to one new student. So far there is one reference student1 and one instance of student that is Frank (new Student("Frank"). Now if you write Student student2 = student1; Then it means that student2 reference is also referring to the same instance of student "Frank". Now there are two reference student1 and student2 both referring to the same student "Frank".

Comment: Now I am clear about the reference comparison. Back to my question, since there are two instances, we need at least two references to begin with. And they won't be equal. All I can assume is, he made a new Student("Frank") and then again a new Student("Frank"). In THIS case, only a unique ID will help. There is no other way to find whether they represent the same student or or two students with the same name and other details. Yes?

Comment: You are right if there are two new Student("Frank") the class should be designed so that both of them should not be equal. I presume you should have suggested the interviewer to keep an ID similar to roll number in class. Like roll number the id will be unique to each student and then you can write equals method where you can compare id too and if the id mismatches then you can tell that both "Frank" are different.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to implement this is to do what most people has said. You can use the inherited method `equals` from the Object class ( which all classes inherit from ). If this is for a larger project, I'd also recommend doing something like this:

Assign a UUID to each and every `Student` object. This gives every student a uniquely identifiable ID, then you can easily compare those two values in the `equals` method. To automatically have it generate a UUID, you can generate a string, based on the hash of all of the attributes, plus some pysudo-random attribute, things like the current time should work. This would prevent overlaps in cases even where two students have the exact same information, because they can't be generated at the exact same time, they'll always have a different UUID.

You could then create a container class, using a `HashMap<String, Student>` to store all students, and create method `getStudentByID(String id)` and `setStudentByID(String id, Student value)` to easily access and manage all students within your collection.

That's how I'd do it, anyways.

**If you want to solve it without implementing extra things** you could use this snippet below.

```
package Snippet1;

public class Snippet1 {
    static class Student {
        public String name;
        public int age;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Student.class)) {
                Student secondStudent = (Student) obj;
                if (secondStudent.age == this.age && secondStudent.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)) {
                    // Student, with all the same information
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Student, but with different information
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not a student!
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Your example ( with little changes )

    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.name = "Jane";
    student1.age =  15;

    Student student2 = new Student();
    student1.name = "John";
    student2.age = 17;

    if (student1.equals(student2)) {
        System.out.println("Same student!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Different student!");
    }

}
```

}